# What is the C++ code to switch from a Main XAML form to a second XAML form

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp, c++-cx, uwp-xaml

I am using visual studio 2015.

I am creating an app that has several forms, but I am stuck because I don't know the code to switch pages.

The MainPage.cpp file code is =

```
//
// MainPage.xaml.cpp
// Implementation of the MainPage class.
//


#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include "IncomeForm.xaml.h"



using namespace pman_project2;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}




void pman_project2::MainPage::Income_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    ??????????????????????????????????????
}
```

The row of question marks is where i am stuck. I have looked online and it tells me how to do it in c# but not c++.

apparently the code in c# is

```
this.Frame.navigate(typeof(page.IncomeForm));
```

can anyone help?

Comment: `c++-cx` is a more appropriate tag than `c++` for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also use this method, but in [C++/CX way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702396.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1):

> **Tip**  If you are programming using a .NET language (C# or Microsoft Visual Basic), the TypeName type projects as System.Type. When programming using C#, it is common to use the typeof operator to get references to the System.Type of a type. In Visual Basic, use GetType. If you're using **C++/CX**, where you'll need to create a **TypeName** helper struct, you can use the [typeid component extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/kwd9abya.aspx).

```
void pman_project2::MainPage::Income_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    this->Frame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(IncomeForm::typeid));
}
```

For advanced usage, please see [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlNavigation/cpp)

Share my sample, please check: [Link](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/NavigationUWPApp2)

Comment: it didn't work, the MainPage::MainPage has a red squiggly line under the the second main page after the 2 colons. also InitializeComponent(); has a red line under it. NavigationUWPApp2 has one as well and "this" sa one as well.

Comment: @jag I updated my code, change the namespace to pman_project2 as yours, I also shared my demo, please check the answer:)